# How can I apply a function to each channel of a three-channel image numpy array without using a for-loop?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Suppose that I have an image of three channels, and its corresponding numpy array is of the shape (H,W,3).
Now I create a function which does something to a 2D numpy array.
How can I apply the funtion to each channel of the image without using a for-loop since it is slow?

I'm looking for a function similar to apply in pandas.
I've tried np.apply_over_axes and np.apply_along_axis, but both results are not correct.

In the code below, I hope to add a gaussian noise seperately to each channel of the image.

```py
test_img = np.array(train_data[0][0])
test_img.shape
# (198, 180, 3)

def add_gaussian_noise(img_, amplitude=1.0, mean=0.0, variance=1.0):
    img_ = img_.astype('float32')
    # print(img_.shape)

    # assertion failed
    # assert img_.shape == (test_img.shape[0], test_img.shape[1])
    img_ = img_ + amplitude * np.random.normal(mean, variance, img_.shape)
    img_ = np.clip(img_, 0.0, 255.0)
    return img_

test_img = np.apply_along_axis(arr= test_img, func1d= add_gaussian_noise, axis = 2)

print(test_img)
```

I'm anticipating that `img_.shape == (test_img.shape[0], test_img.shape[1])`, but it turns out that `img_.shape == (3,)` in my code.

In this case, the optimization won't make a big difference, but I am looking for a more generalized solution so that in other cases, e.g. I have to apply the same function to hundreds of grayscale pictures, the code works more efficiently than the for-loop.

Comment: Could you be more elaborative about what sort of function you want to apply? IMO, you won't get much optimization for just 3 iterations since you're taking one channel (2D array) at once.

Comment: A small number of iterations (only 3!) on a relatively complex task is no big deal.  There aren't any "shortcuts" that will speed this up; at best they'll just hide the loop.  Don't bother with those "apply..." functions.

Comment: I'm sorry that I have made it not clear. Now I update my question, adding a code block. I am looking for a more generalized solution so that in other cases, e.g. I have to apply the same function to hundreds of grayscale pictures, the code works more efficiently than the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). This allows you to run operations on multiple slices of an array. Without more information, it's impossible to say if this will work in your specific case, but this is the normal way to do this sort of thing using Numpy.

Many Numpy functions support broadcasting (you'll see references to this in the documentation). This is frequently done on the early matrix axes, so you may need to transpose your channels axis to the start of the matrix.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, for a small number of repetitions, looping in Python is a perfectly reasonable approach. But I assume you're looking for a more general case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm still a little confused in my specfic case. Now I've updated my code, could you please tell me how to edit the code?